# Installing Biopython from academic Enthought Canopy 32bit Windows 7

Tags: installation, enthought, biopython

When I try to use the Canopy Package Manager and "subscribe" to Biopython I am asked to pay for it.  Can I use the package manager w/o paying?

Answer (score 1):

No, I think you do not need to pay for that if you dont wish to. All you need to do is to install biopython independent of canopy some where in your machine say "/path/to/biopython"
and in canopy add import sys and sys.path.append('/path/to/biopython') will do the job!